# Change color of a cell based on the difference between 2 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

My question is I have 2 cells, A1 and B1, I would like to have the color of B1 change color base on the difference of both cells. Example value of A1 is 10 and value of B1 is 100, as the value in A1 changes and gets closer to B1, within 25, I want the format color to change to Red. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula as your formatting condition:

```
=B1-A1<25
```

[image]

If it is possible that A1 will be greater than B1, and you *only* want to match when they're within 25 of each other, use this instead:

```
=ABS(B1-A1)<25
```

[image]

If you want to cover a whole column, but keep the blanks looking pretty, wrap it in an AND with a NOT ISBLANK added on.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),B1-A1<25)
```

[image]

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),ABS(B1-A1)<25)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't think it was going to be that easy.

Comment: Basic on/off Conditional Formatting is fairly simple - just give it a formula that evaluates to TRUE when you want the formatting applied, and FALSE when you don't.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with:

> Conditional formatting

Create a new rule like so:

[image]

And then adjust the rule to suit your needs:

[image]

If you choose `number` for the highest and lowest value then you'll be able to reference a cell, i.e your B2

Comment: I have tried this and I cannot make it work. perhaps I can explain how I use it. Cell A1 is time entered from another worksheet lets say 10hrs but only 10.0 is the value of cell A1. I have an inspection due at 100.0hrs, that information is entered into cell B1. I need to be able to see that when A1 reaches 75.0hrs cell B1 (100.0hrs) will now be red because I am within my 25hr window for inspection. Both cells A and B with be changed with different times as I go along. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bryon So you want a simple formatting toggle, not a progressive scale?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting to add a rule which uses a formula to determine when to change the format.

Enter the formula `=A1>=75`, then set what formatting you want by using the <kbd>Format...</kbd> button.

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and there should be a new rule in your conditional formatting window.

[image]

As long as you have caclulation set to automatic, anytime the number in `A1` gets to 75 or higher then `B1` will have the formatting applied.

Comment: Thanks but these numbers are just made up numbers. I need Cell B1 to change anytime A1 comes within 25 hours of what ever number I put into B1. This time it might be A1=9130.0 and B1=9155.0 at this point I need Cell B1 to change to Red. Next time it might be A1=9250.0 and B1=9275.0 and the formula should still be the same and still turn Cell B1 to red because A1 is within 25.0hrs or less. Thanks for your input.

Comment: In that case use this as the formula =A1>=B1-25

Comment: That clarity would have been useful. I agree with @DanSmith on that.